# hierarchical search in ElasticSearch

Tags: c#, elasticsearch

Sorry if this question is repeated. I did check something called parent-child relationship, but want to confirm if it'll help me with my use case.

```
{
  "person": {
    "name": "Bob Smith",
    "phones": [
      {
        "type": "MOB",
        "number": 12345
      },
      {
        "type": "HOME",
        "number": 54321
      }
    ],
    "email": "bob@smith.com"
  }
}
```

If that's a document I have in ElasticSearch DB and I'm searching for:

```
Name: Bob Smith
PhoneType: MOB
PhoneNumber: 12345
Email: bob@smith.com
```

I would obviously get the correct document. But if my search is:

```
Name: Bob Smith
PhoneType: MOB
PhoneNumber: 73827
Email: bob@smith.com
```

I would not get any documents, but instead can I get back some information like 'found the person with the email, but not with that phone'?

I think I can do a multi-search by passing only name in the first request, name+email in the second one, name+phone(type and number) in the third and name+email+phone(type and number).

But want to know if this is the only way to do it.

Thanks,
Arun

Answer (score 0):

You can send one [boolean query of `should` type](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html) that have four clauses, one for each of the fields you want to check (`Name`, `PhoneType`, `PhoneNumber`, `Email`). This way, you will get a document if you got a hit for any of your clauses. The more the hits, the higher the score of the hit.

Comment: sir, I'm a little occupied an a production issue now; will surely try this and let you know. In the meantime, do you know the NEST C# version of this query? If not, it's ok, I should be able to build it.

Answer (score 0):

Tried @glencota's suggestion, but it doesn't necessarily tell me at what level/filter the data matched. Since our API needs to inform to our clients 'found the person with the email, but not with that phone', we won't be able to use the boolean option in Elastic.

We'll go ahead and implement this as part of a multi-search use case.

Thanks @glencota for your time sir.